# PHP Proxy Server and Calling JSON Code Problem?

Tags: php, html, json, proxy

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052643/php-proxy-server-and-calling-json) I am using the code provided in one of the answers.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>



<?php

$server_url = "http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.json";

$options = array
(
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET        => 1
);

$service = $_GET["service"];

$request_headers = Array();
foreach($_SERVER as $i=>$val) {
        if (strpos($i, 'HTTP_') === 0) {
                $name = str_replace(array('HTTP_', '_'), array('', '-'), $i);
                if ($name != 'HOST')
                {
                    $request_headers[] = "{$name}: {$val}";
                }
        }
}

$options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $request_headers;

switch (strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]))
{

    case "post":
        $options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        $url = "{$server_url}/services/".$service;

        $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = file_get_contents("php://input");

        break;
    case "get":

        unset($_GET["service"]);

        $querystring = "";
        $first = true;
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $val)
        {
            if (!$first) $querystring .= "&";
            $querystring .= $key."=".$val;
            $first = false;
        }

        $url = "{$server_url}/services/".$service."?".$querystring;

        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unsupported request method.");
        break;

}

$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $url;

$curl_handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl_handle,$options);
$server_output = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$response = explode("\r\n\r\n",$server_output);
$headers = explode("\r\n",$response[0]);

foreach ($headers as $header)
{
    if ( !preg_match(';^transfer-encoding:;ui', Trim($header))  )
    {
        header($header);
    }
}

echo $response[1]; 


?> 



</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I get the following errors, why is this?:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php:12) in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 88 Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php:12) in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 88 Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php:12) in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 88 Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php:12) in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 88 Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php:12) in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 88 Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php:12) in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 88 Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php:12) in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 88 Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php:12) in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 88 Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php:12) in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 88 HTTP/1.1
>   404 Not Found Server: Apache Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 224
>   Cache-Control: max-age=7146 Expires: Sat, 13 Aug 2011 22:12:11 GMT
>   Date: Sat, 13 Aug 2011 20:13:05 GMT Connection: keep-alive Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding X-Akamai-Edgescape: country_code=US

Comment: Please edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052643/php-proxy-server-and-calling-json or ask the one who provided you with that answer.

Comment: @shi - this is fair enough as a new question because it's a problem with the code provided by the person that answered that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot echo anything out before calling `header` so in your case its all of the stuff before your opening php tags.

Your best bet would be to do all of your php before your opening `html` tag